# colorbox css display problems in IE

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I have a page use Colorbox plug in, The Css display wrong in IE (all versions).

1. colorbox size is wrong when it pop
2. colorbox cross position is wrong

I have put`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` in my file.

i tried `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it also not work

I test on IE, if I turn IE to quirks mode, it display correct.

anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: have you tried validating your HTML? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: You're probably not going to get much help unless you provide code.